# Does the trainer you use make a difference?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know each trainer can only train you up to a certain level in their skill:

- Common: Up to 50
- Expert: Up to 75
- Master: Up to 90

Aside from this, does it make a difference which level trainer I go to?  Will training with a Master trainer give me more XP than a Common trainer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two minor considerations:

1. Certain trainers can become followers, which basically means you can get free training by training and then opening up their inventory to take back your gold.
2. Some trainers requires you to join their guild before granting you training.

Other than that, who you are training with has no affect on xp or cost.

Comment: And some trainers are merchant, so you can get your money back by trading.

Comment: @yx Is there a list somewhere of all the follower-trainers?

Comment: @Iszi not that I know of, but you can pull up a list of trainers and a list of followers and cross correlate.

Comment: @Iszi Faendal is on example.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the trainer's is how high they are able to train you.  Each advancement gives you some xp, regardless of how it improves.

You can see how XP is calculated here:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling

You can see the cost of trainers here:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Trainers#Notes